# Lambda expression with generic

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8

I'm learning lambda expressions in Java, however, I have thought to use it with generic types. (e.g. int, String). As far as I learn and research to use lambda expression in Java, it must be declared in a interface. Then, define its implementation where you'd like to use. (i.e. `(prototype args) -> {definition}` ). I have tried writing just basic example with type problem as you can see below. I have just thought to use it with `String`, `int` types as an exercise. But, I can't initialize the generic type to `0`. I can do for `null`. I'm not sure that whether `null` is equal `0` for that way. How can the issue be resolved?

```
public class Test<T,U> {

    public static <T,U> void main(String[] args) {

        Test myTest = new Test();

        Str myHello = (message1, message2) -> {
                            System.out.println("Hello " + message1 + message2);};

        myHello.welcome("Mr. ", "rickroll");

        MyGen addition = (U... operationArgs) -> {
                            T sum = 0;
                            for (U i : operationArgs) {
                                sum += i;
                            }
                            return sum;};

        System.out.println("2+3+4+5 = " + myTest.operate(addition, 2, 3, 4, 5));

        System.out.println("A.....gl ?" + myTest.operate(addition, "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"));
    }

    private T operate(MyGen choice, U... args) {
        return (T)choice.asYouWish(args);
    }

    interface Str {
        public void welcome(String a, String b);
    }

    interface MyGen<T,U> {
        public T asYouWish(U... args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Initializing a generic type to `0` makes no sense. What if `T` is of type `List<String>` ?

Comment: If you know C++, then don't confuse Java generics with what you know from templates in C++. Java generics are not like C++ templates. You cannot assign `0` to a variable of type `T` because `T` could be any type, and you cannot assign `0` to any arbitrary type. Also `+=` cannot be used on any arbitrary type.

Comment: No, it's not. `T` can be anything. I could create a new instance: `new Test<List<String>, 2DPoint>()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring several type parameters without using them and perhaps not even understanding that these are independent type parameters despite having the same name. And when you declare a class with type parameters, you have to declare type arguments when using that class.

So when you define a class like

```
public class Test<T,U> {
    public static <T,U> void main(String[] args) { … }
    private T operate(MyGen choice, U... args) { … }
    interface MyGen<T,U> {
        public T asYouWish(U... args);
    }
}
```

it’s not different to declaring

```
public class Test<T,U> {
    public static <A,B> void main(String[] args) { … }
    private T operate(MyGen choice, U... args) { … }
    interface MyGen<X,Y> {
        public X asYouWish(Y... args);
    }
}
```

as naming them all `T` and `U` does not create a relationship but is only confusing a human reader. The type parameters of a class affect its non-`static` members only and the only non-`static` member of `Test` is the method `operate`, which refers to `MyGen` without actual type arguments.

A correct usage would be

```
private T operate(MyGen<T,U> choice, U... args) {
    return choice.asYouWish(args);
}
```

so you are declaring that the `MyGen` parameter must be parametrized accordingly to the `Test`’s parametrization, which now enables you to invoke `asYouWish` without warnings and without type casts.

It should be emphasized that you can’t use the same instance of `Test` to use the method for `String`s and `Integer`s as you define the type arguments for `T` and `U` when instantiating `Test`.

Further, the type parameters of the `main` method are independent of the `Test`’s type parameters and since they are not used in the method’s signature, quite useless. Referring to them within the lambda expression is pointless, even if there was no compiler error within the lambda expression’s body, there are no instances of that type in scope to use the function.

Putting it together, you get

```
public class Test<T,U> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Str myHello = (message1, message2) ->
                        System.out.println("Hello " + message1 + message2);
        myHello.welcome("Mr. ", "rickroll");

        {
            Test<Integer,Integer> myTest = new Test();
            MyGen<Integer,Integer> addition = operationArgs -> {
                int sum = 0;
                for(int i: operationArgs) sum += i;
                return sum;
            };
            System.out.println("2+3+4+5 = " + myTest.operate(addition, 2, 3, 4, 5));
        }
        {
            Test<String,String> myTest = new Test();
            MyGen<String,String> addition = operationArgs -> {
                String sum = "";
                for(String i: operationArgs) sum += i;
                return sum;
            };
            System.out.println("A.....gl ?"
                + myTest.operate(addition, "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"));
        }
    }
    private T operate(MyGen<T,U> choice, U... args) {
        return choice.asYouWish(args);
    }
    interface Str {
        public void welcome(String a, String b);
    }
    interface MyGen<X,Y> {
        public X asYouWish(Y... args);
    }
}
```

You can get rid of the requirement to parametrize the `Test` instance, by simply turning the `operate` into a generic `static` method as the instance is not needed anyway. If you want to define a generic `MyGen` function, you have to abstract the `+` operator, as unlike its appearance in the `String` case, there is no operator overloading in Java.

Further, you have to implement it without needing a neutral element, as `0` doesn’t magically turn into the empty string, when attempting to use the same function with strings.

```
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Str myHello = (message1, message2) ->
                        System.out.println("Hello " + message1 + message2);
        myHello.welcome("Mr. ", "rickroll");

        example(Integer::sum, "2+3+4+5 = ", 2, 3, 4, 5);
        example(String::concat, "A.....gl ?", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f");
    }
    private static <E> void example(BinaryOperator<E> plus, String head, E... values) {
        MyGen<E,E> addition = args -> {
            E sum=args[0];
            for(int ix=1; ix<args.length; ix++) sum = plus.apply(sum, args[ix]);
            return sum;
        };
        System.out.println(head + Test.operate(addition, values));
    }
    private static <T,U> T operate(MyGen<T,U> choice, U... args) {
        return choice.asYouWish(args);
    }
    interface Str {
        public void welcome(String a, String b);
    }
    interface MyGen<X,Y> {
        public X asYouWish(Y... args);
    }
}
```

This is only for demonstration purposes as that work has already been made, e.g. you could change the `example` method to:

```
private static <E> void example(BinaryOperator<E> plus, String head, E... values) {
    MyGen<E,E> addition = args -> Arrays.stream(args).reduce(plus).get();
    System.out.println(head + Test.operate(addition, values));
}
```